# Checking if something is set using a Laravel pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, hierarchy

I have a Laravel database with a table for `tags`, a table for `items` and a table for `item_tag`. The tags are hierarchical, and as a result, I'm trying to query which tags have been set inside a loop.

That's easy, I just use `$item->tags` and it gives me my tags in an accessible object, ready to loop through.

The problem appears when I want to check if a specific object is set, when showing a list of *all* tags. I'm using the following code for testing:

```
function buildTree($tags, $selected = null) {
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            echo "<li>";
                if($selected[$tag->id]) {
                    echo "<strong>";
                }
                echo $tag->name;
                if($selected[$tag->id]) {
                    echo "</strong>";
                }
                if($tag->children) {
                    buildTree($tag->children);
                }
            echo "</li>";
        }
    echo "</ul>";
}
$item = Item::find(1);
$tags = Tag::whereNull('tag_id')->get();
buildTree($tags, $item->tags);
```

The expected output would be that each tag that is selected would come up as bold in the tree. Of course, if that had happened, I wouldn't be posting this. Instead, it just highlights the first item in the tree, even though it isn't selected. (That's because `$selected` isn't supposed to be addressed that way).

What's the correct way to get this information?

Comment: I think there's a couple basic approaches you could do. Tag::get() will return an collection object of type "\Illuminate\Support\Collection" which has a lot of functions you can exploit. Perhaps, you could use the following in your if clause:

$selected->where('id', $tag->id)

Also, you could play with the data before you introduce to your function. Something like this, depending on your version of Laravel: 

Tag::whereNull('tag_id')->get(['id'])->pluck('id);

Comment: @mattcrowe Funnily enough, I actually figured it out before I noticed your comment. I discovered that there were many methods that can be used with a Collection, and I successfully used `contains` to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> That's because $selected isn't supposed to be addressed that way

Then how's it got to be addressed? Of course the answer lies there itself, since you rely on $selected for checking what tags were selected.

As per your comment, the following should solve your problem

Change your if condition from this -

```
if($selected[$tag->id])
```

To This -

```
if(array_in($tag->id, $selected))
```

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. The problem lies in the fact that there is no `$selected[$tag->id]`, `$selected` is just an array starting at 0, and isn't related to the ID. I'm trying to find a way to find if the `$tag->id` is in the `$selected` object.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Hope that solves the problem. You may refer to array_in() documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunetly it wasn't working because I was trying regular array and object techniques on a Laravel Collection. I've done some research and discovered that there is a dedicated method for finding this data!

Answer (score 0):

I found a functioning solution using the [Collections API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections) in Laravel, utilising `contains`.

```
if($selected != null && $selected->contains('id', $tag->id))
```

This seems to be the most convenient way to find the data, and it functions perfectly in my application.